# Establish JSForce Connection through Google Authentication

Tags: google, node.js, jsforce, ionic

I am developing an application with the **Ionic Framework**, and my requirement is to login to Salesforce, make a connection to **JSForce** to be able to use their **REST API**.

I will try and explain this briefly. Originally, the connection was done through **Salesforce OAuth** : I open an InAppBrowser with the **salesforce login page**, the user enters his credentials, and with the parameters in the redirect link, I make my connection to JSForce, and then get an access token that will allow me to make my REST API Requests (to Apex Classes I configured myself).

> More info : https://jsforce.github.io/document/#oauth2

Up until now, everything works perfectly.

However, this Salesforce OAuth Implementation is **not very user friendly** since he has to log back in every few hours. I was asked to put in place a **Google Authentication Provider** to make things more user friendly. 
For that, I followed this tutorial : http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/kcgTXQytUb6INIs2g3faKg

I created my Google App and linked it to Salesforce, everything is fine, the login works well on browser.
I configured it so the default login page for Salesforce is Google, now if I open the link to my domain it redirects to the Google Login Page, which is what I want (to make it easier for the user to login).

In my Ionic Application, I open the InAppBrowser with the link to my Salesforce. I am automatically redirected to Google, but I get this error :

> 403. That's an error.
>
> Error : disallowed_useragent
>
> This user-agent is not permitted to make an OAuth authorization
>   request to Google as it classified as an embedded user-agent (also
>   known as a web-view) [...]

Okay, so this is because I am using the InAppBrowser, but it's fine because there is a plugin that allows me to do what I wanted in the first place : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/

Now I can login in to Salesforce via Google thanks to this plugin that is authorized by Google.
After a classic Salesforce OAuth login, it returned an Access Token, the ID of the user and the instance URL, enough for me to establish my JSForce connection as such :

```
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    accessToken: req.query.access_token,
    instanceUrl: req.query.instance_url
});
```

All I have returned from the Google Login is this:

```
accessToken: '************'

displayName: "display name"

email: "name@company.com"

familyName: "family name"

givenName: "name"

idToken: '*************'

imageUrl: '*********'

refreshToken: '*************'

serverAuthCode: "" (this one always comes back blank to me)

userId: "************"
```

**Is it even possible for me to make a JSForce connection with what I have, or do I have to give up on the idea ?**

**If not, how else can I establish my connection to Salesforce with a Google Access Token?**